# Get entry in a table depending on the latest value in a related table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, greatest-n-per-group

I have a trivial looking request in Postgresql but I just can't crack it.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dc955/31

**File Upload Table:**

```
id  file_name
1   file001
2   file002
3   file003
4   file004
```

**File Status Table:**

```
id  file_upload_id  file_status_id  status_date
1   1                1               October, 16 2015 19:22:51
2   1                2               October, 17 2015 09:19:20
3   1                3               October, 17 2015 09:20:51
4   1                4               October, 17 2015 09:22:51
5   2                1               October, 17 2015 13:45:10
6   3                1               October, 17 2015 09:22:57
7   1                1               October, 17 2015 23:22:12
```

**Config File Status:**

```
id  status_code status_name
1   001          Unprocessed
2   002          Queued
3   003          Staging
4   004          Production
```

Got three tables: **file_upload** <--> **file_status** <--> **config_file_status**. The **file_status** table holds the various status a file can go through during processing

What I need is to get the `file_upload.id, file_upload.file_name, file_status.file_status_id` for files whose latest/newest `file_status_id = 1` i.e. Unprocessed which is actually the status created by the upload app when a file is initially uploaded

I've tried so far:

```
select file_upload.file_name, 
max(file_status.file_status_id) as latest_status
from file_upload, file_status, config_file_status
where file_upload.id = file_status.file_upload_id and
file_status.file_status_id = config_file_status.id 
Group By file_upload.file_name;
```

Not only does it not return the correct latest status of file001 but the query feels like an over kill.

What am looking for is the correct SQL syntax to achieve the above but if you can, also provide the same in SQLAlchemy Core.

Using Postgresql 9.3

Answer (score 4):

You can use `distinct on (s.file_upload_id)`. Put `status_date desc` in `order by` to have latest upload date for each file.

```
select distinct on (s.file_upload_id) 
    s.file_upload_id, 
    u.file_name,
    s.file_status_id
from file_status s
join file_upload u on u.id = s.file_upload_id
where file_status_id = 1
order by file_upload_id, status_date desc;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dc955/41)

If you search for `file_status_id` only in the latest uploads, move where clause outside the query:

```
select *
from (
    select distinct on (s.file_upload_id) 
        s.file_upload_id, 
        u.file_name,
        s.file_status_id
    from file_status s
    join file_upload u on u.id = s.file_upload_id
    order by file_upload_id, status_date desc
    ) sub
where file_status_id = 2;
```

Comment: This seems to return the correct results but it breaks when you change the file_status_id. If you were to substitute the file_status_id with 2 instead of 1, it still gives you a result. It seems to be fetching any file which has got the specified status even if its not the latest. [sqlfiddle for changed file_status_id](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c022d/2). @a_horse_with_no_name below works. Please confirm.

Comment: It's some kind of misunderstanding. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

This type of problem is typically solved by using a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select id, file_name, status_date, file_status_id
from (
  SELECT fu.id, 
         fu.file_name, 
         fs.status_date, 
         fs.file_status_id,
         row_number() over (partition by fu.id order by fs.status_date desc) as rn
  FROM file_upload fu
    LEFT JOIN file_status fs ON fu.id = fs.file_upload_id
) t
where rn = 1
  and file_status_id = 1
order by id, file_name;
```

Comment: Seems to be working okay even if I change the file_status_id to e.g. 2 or 3. Any chance of being able to put this in SQlAlchemy core?

Comment: @lukik: sorry, no idea I don't use SQLAlchemy (or any other obfuscation layer)

Answer (score 1):

```
        select u.id, u.file_name, s.file_status_id, s.status_date 
        from 
        file_upload u, file_status s 
        where u.id = s.file_upload_id
        and 
        s.status_date = (select max(s.status_date) from file_status s 
        where u.id = s.file_upload_id) and s.file_status_id = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dc955/52